# Converting to and from epoch time

Tags: time

I often find myself needing to convert from one type of time to another, and haven't found a way I'm consistently happy with. Every time I do a quick google search, I come up with different (sometimes painfully complex) answers.

I'm happy with

```
date -d "Sep 5 1986" "+%s"
```

for converting a standard date to epoch time, but I can't seem to make the reverse work (and the man pages I've browsed aren't helping much.)

```
date -d "526276800" "+%m/%d/%y"
```

yields an error on my RHEL 5 install.

Can the community offer me some strategies for easily converting back and forth? I'll take all forms: awk, perl, date. What are the pros and cons of each method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

date -d @526276800 "+%m/%d/%y"

Comment: Ah ha! That's the notation I was looking for, thanks! I can't believe this didn't come up for me in my google searches.

Comment: I can't believe it's not in the man page for date.

Comment: I wondered that myself -- after a quick look at the bottom of the man page, I noticed that (at least on my RHEL 5 system) there is further documentation available in the info pages and the syntax is listed there (though I did have to follow something like 4 links to get there)

Comment: For the Red Hat centered here, like myself: this works from RHEL4 and up. The date command in RHEL3 is of the 4.x branch, which does not have this functionality.

Answer (score 4):

On my Mac OS X box, I use:

```
date -r 526276800 +%m/%d/%y
```

Comment: This is on at least Mac OS X and OpenBSD. May be present on other BSD derived systems, too.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU date:

date  -d '1970-01-01 946684800 seconds'

Comment: That's a nice trick!

Answer (score 1):

Or in Ruby:

```
% ruby -e 'puts Time.now.to_f'
1243620267.8988

% ruby -e 'puts Time.now.to_i'
1243620267

% ruby -e 'puts Time.at 1243620270'
Fri May 29 11:04:30 -0700 2009

% ruby -e 'puts Time.at(1243620270).strftime "at %I:%M%p"'
at 11:04AM
```

Here are the `strftime` formats, taken from the ruby `Time` class documentation:

```
  %a - The abbreviated weekday name (``Sun'')
  %A - The  full  weekday  name (``Sunday'')
  %b - The abbreviated month name (``Jan'')
  %B - The  full  month  name (``January'')
  %c - The preferred local date and time representation
  %d - Day of the month (01..31)
  %H - Hour of the day, 24-hour clock (00..23)
  %I - Hour of the day, 12-hour clock (01..12)
  %j - Day of the year (001..366)
  %m - Month of the year (01..12)
  %M - Minute of the hour (00..59)
  %p - Meridian indicator (``AM''  or  ``PM'')
  %S - Second of the minute (00..60)
  %U - Week  number  of the current year,
          starting with the first Sunday as the first
          day of the first week (00..53)
  %W - Week  number  of the current year,
          starting with the first Monday as the first
          day of the first week (00..53)
  %w - Day of the week (Sunday is 0, 0..6)
  %x - Preferred representation for the date alone, no time
  %X - Preferred representation for the time alone, no date
  %y - Year without a century (00..99)
  %Y - Year with century
  %Z - Time zone name
  %% - Literal ``%'' character
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -le 'print scalar localtime 1243620900'
Fri May 29 11:15:00 2009
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little heavy duty, but in perl there's a great module called DateTime that'll convert back and forth between a myriad of date & time formats, including epoch.  It's very simple to use:

http://datetime.perl.org/

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I alternatively use Python and bash for this. But since you are annoyed with it ;-) I'd go for making a small script that takes a date as a parameter and write it so as to have --2epoch and --2normal options.

That way, you can convert from epoch to normal with

```
./script.sh --2normal 1243609635
```

and the other way around with

```
./script --2epoch "20090529 17:07"
```

Is the input date always formatted the same way? That would make the script a lot easier to write.

Answer (score 0):

Perl one-liner:

$ perl -MDate::Manip -le 'print UnixDate(ParseDateString("epoch ".shift()),"%c")' 946684800

Answer (score 0):

## FROM epoch:

dump epoch timestamps to readable forms from stdin (first example)
or as args (second example), and dont forget the power of strftime!

`perl -pe '$_=~s/(\d{10})/scalar localtime($1)/eg'`

`perl -e '$s=join(" ",@ARGV);$s=~s/(\d{10})/scalar localtime($1)/eg;print"$s\n"'`

`perl -pe 'use POSIX qw(strftime);s/(\d{10,10})/strftime("%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S",$1)/eg'`

## TO epoch:

If you have Date::Manip module installed for perl (which usually ISNT there by default), you can use:

`perl -MDate::Manip -e '$stamp=UnixDate(ParseDate(join(" ",@ARGV)),"%s");printf"%d %s\n",$stamp,scalar localtime($stamp)' sep 9 2006`

Sometimes it's hard to decide if you want to REPLACE the timestamps in your 'filter',
or if you want to preface the line with the timestamp found.  I flip back-n-forth on that one.